# XmlDocument.Load() => XmlException at "percent" char

Tags: c#, xml, compact-framework

When I try to load a xmlfile which has the '%' in an attribute, I get a XmlException at the position of the '%'. See at the Example in the tag 'humidity'

```
<current_conditions>
  <condition data="Klar"/>
  <temp_f data="63"/>
  <temp_c data="17"/>
  <humidity data="Feuchtigkeit: 30 %"/>
  <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/>
  <wind_condition data="Wind: W mit 34 km/h"/>
</current_conditions>
```

Loading the XmlDocument with [xmlDoc](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=74366,Deutschland&hl=de):

```
private void ParseXML(string url) {
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(url);
}
```

Comment: What is the text of the exception?

Comment: What is the exception? (It may be a "clue")

Comment: "Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 529."

Comment: The URL is already in the Question [xmlDoc] ...

Comment: Don't know the root cause, but I confirm that both XmlDocument and XDocument throw the same on the URL posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an encoding problem.
You can work around it by using `WebClient`, like this:

```
private void ParseXML(string url) {
    string xmlSource;
    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        xmlSource = wc.DownloadString(url);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlSource);
}
```

(Tested)

Comment: Except for the fact that the WebClient class doesn't exist in the CF.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm using the WebRequest wc = HttpWebRequest.Create(url); for now. But I wonder if there is a way to change the Encoding in the XmlDocument itself?